# How to clear console of postman programmatically

Tags: javascript, postman-pre-request-script

I'm trying to write assertions for api testing using postman. In order to debug I'm using console.log() function, which is cluttering the console of Postman.

I've tried `console.clear();` in pre-request script but get TypeError.

Error in postman:

[image]

Can I programmatically clear the console in pre-request Script or Test section of Postman?

Answer (score 5):

"Can I programmatically clear the console in pre-request Script or Test section of Postman?"

Not yet, but it's on the wish-list...

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4690

Answer (score 4):

It has now been implemented!
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4690#issuecomment-1347768736

```
console.clear();
```